# Connect-Mongo Heroku Error - Error setting TTL index on collection : sessions

Tags: mongodb, heroku, express, mongoose

I'm trying to deploy a vanilla MEAN stack app via Heroku, however the app crashes upon loading it due to this issue with Mongo-Connect.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can fix this?

**[Here is the MEAN stack app](https://github.com/linnovate/mean)**

Below is the error:

```
    Error: Error setting TTL index on collection : sessions 
Nov 17 12:17:45  appone app/web.1:      at /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:161:23 
Nov 17 12:17:45  appone app/web.1:      at /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1246:28 
Nov 17 12:17:45  appone app/web.1:      at /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1384:30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I was using two separate logins for the DB.  The url credentials in my heroku config environment variables was different from the url credentials in my production.json file.